# What would cause "SQLException while executing plsql statement: call sImportLookup.get_by_ext_id_text"?

Tags: externalid

I am getting the error below when I try to insert a record with an external id:

> Error:
>   ORA-20000: ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.SIMPORTLOOKUP", line 850 ORA-06512: at "SNEEZY.SIMPORTLOOKUP", line 823 ORA-06512: at line 1 : SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call sImportLookup.get_by_ext_id_text(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}([ a0co00000023vjzmaya04o0000000sspdiac, a0co00000023vjzmaya04o0000000sspeiac, a0co00000023vjzmaya04o0000000sspfiac ][Ljava.lang.String;@6e622490, a0D, custom_entity_data_id, 0, 0, false, system.plsql.ResultSetOutParam@6d4ea28d)

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Can some one explain what causes this error?

Comment: We're going to need more information.  Were you using the Data Loader or a different tool?  What object and data were you changing?  Is it one record or multiple?  The error message by itself doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Unfortunately that screenshot is basically illegible and since it's an image instead of text it's also unsearchable.  Please copy and paste the full text of the error in your question along with reproduction steps.  That will get you a better answer and make the question and answer more searchable/usable on this site.  However, the error looks like an internal Salesforce.com error and you'll most likely need to contact support to get it resolved.

Comment: Is the code for SNEEZY.SIMPORTLOOKUP yours or is it coming from someone else? If it is yours, what is happening on lines 850 and 823?

Comment: On apex code i am doing upsert on list.  It is custom object. Master Detail to another Custom Object.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an internal Salesforce.com error, possibly the result of a bug.  Notice the similar error encountered by another user in 2009 at this link: [similar error](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Partner-Relationship-Management/Error-while-adding-a-Product-to-an-Opportunity-as-a-Portal-User/td-p/121624)

I would contact Salesforce.com support directly to get this resolved.  When or if you get an answer for them, please add the answer here as well.

Comment: Its an internal oracle error, and its a bug (and its also a bug that its being reported externally)

Comment: @superfell can you settle an office bet, is sneezy a validation system or something else entirley?

Comment: something else entirely

Answer (score 3):

Got response from salesforce.

opt_external_id​​ is an optional variable that specifies the custom field that should be used to match records that already exist in your organization's data. This custom field must be created with the External Id attribute selected. Additionally, if the field does not have the Unique attribute selected, the context user must have the “View All” object-level permission for the target object or the “View All Data” permission so that upsert does not accidentally insert a duplicate record.

Comment: appreciate you putting in support's response here for the community's benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely looks like an internal error that Salesforce are encountering, lookup up the error codes I found this:

> ORA-20000: ORU-10027: buffer overflow, limit of 2000 bytes

on one forum, and `ORA-6512` is used for reporting problem line numbers:

> Error: ORA-06512: at line  Cause: This error message indicates
>   the line number in the PLSQL code that the error resulted.

Salesforce support will be the way to go unless any Salesforce guys on here have a magic bullet answer!